# can't bring to front a full LinearLayout in a practice android app

Tags: android, bringtofront

It seems I am not able to get the startingPlayerLayout to the front of other Views. I have tried multiple solutions, the last one being the code below, which as a result keeps the LinearLayout visible but in the background...
(It's my very first question on Stack Overflow, please excuse any mistakes)
Thanks to everyone

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

boolean gameFinished = false;

// Player 1 = Black, Player 2 = Red

int playerActive;
int[] gameState = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int[][] winningPositions = {{0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}, {0, 3, 6}, {1, 4, 7}, {2, 5, 8}, {0, 4, 8}, {2, 4, 6}};

TextView gameInfoField;
Button playAgainButton;
LinearLayout startingPlayerLayout;
ConstraintLayout baseLayout;

// The actual gameplay follows:

public void player1Starts(View view) {
    playerActive = 1;
    startingPlayerLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

public void player2Starts(View view) {
    playerActive = 2;
    startingPlayerLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

public void playCounter(View view) {
    ImageView counter = (ImageView) view;
    int squarePlayed = Integer.parseInt(counter.getTag().toString());
    gameInfoField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gameInfoField);
    if (!gameFinished) {
        if (gameState[squarePlayed] == 0) {
        counter.setTranslationY(-1000f);
            if (playerActive == 1) {
            counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.token_black);
            gameState[squarePlayed] = 1;
            playerActive = 2;
            gameInfoField.setText("Tocca al ROSSO");
            } else {
            counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.token_red);
            gameState[squarePlayed] = 2;
            playerActive = 1;
            gameInfoField.setText("Tocca al NERO");
            }
        counter.animate().translationYBy(1000f);
        } else if (gameState[squarePlayed] == 0 && !gameFinished) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "La casella è già occupata", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    // Need to check if there's a winner, or if it's a draw:

        for (int[] winningPosition : winningPositions) {
            playAgainButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playAgainButton);
            if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == gameState[winningPosition[1]] &&
                gameState[winningPosition[1]] == gameState[winningPosition[2]] &&
                gameState[winningPosition[0]] != 0) {
                gameFinished = true;
                if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == 1) {
                    gameInfoField.setText("IL NERO VINCE!");
                } else {
                    gameInfoField.setText("IL ROSSO VINCE!");
                }
                gameFinished = true;
                playAgainButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            boolean fullBoard = true;
            for (int square : gameState) {
                if (square == 0) {
                    fullBoard = false;
                }
            }
            if (fullBoard && !gameFinished) {
                gameInfoField.setText("Pareggio");
                playAgainButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Abbiamo già un vincitore!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

// And finally, we need to be able to play again if we want to:

public void playAgain(View view) {
    gameFinished = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < gameState.length; i++) {
        gameState[i] = 0;
    }
    GridLayout board = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.board);
    for (int i = 0; i < board.getChildCount(); i++) {
        ((ImageView) board.getChildAt(i)).setImageResource(0);
    }
    playAgainButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    baseLayout.bringChildToFront(startingPlayerLayout);
    startingPlayerLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if (playerActive == 1) {
        gameInfoField.setText("Tocca al NERO");
    }
    else {
        gameInfoField.setText("Tocca al ROSSO");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    baseLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.baseLayout);
    startingPlayerLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.startingPlayerLayout);
    baseLayout.bringChildToFront(startingPlayerLayout);
    startingPlayerLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
}
```

And here is the XML file (I tried to move the LinearLayout at the end of it but the problem remains the same):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/baseLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    tools:context="com.williamzannoni.tris.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/startingPlayerLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/startingPlayerText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CHI COMINCIA?"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="5dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/startingBlackButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/colorButtonNormal"
            android:onClick="player1Starts"
            android:text="NERO" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/startingRedButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:onClick="player2Starts"
            android:text="ROSSO" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/board"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="368dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/board_grey"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:elevation="1dp"
        android:rowCount="3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.496">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:onClick="playCounter"
            android:tag="0" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:onClick="playCounter"
            android:tag="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:onClick="playCounter"
            android:tag="2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:onClick="playCounter"
            android:tag="3" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:onClick="playCounter"
            android:tag="4" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:onClick="playCounter"
            android:tag="5" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:onClick="playCounter"
            android:tag="6" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView9"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:onClick="playCounter"
            android:tag="7" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:onClick="playCounter"
            android:tag="8" />

    </GridLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gameInfoField"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Tocca al NERO"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/board"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.727" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/playAgainButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:onClick="playAgain"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="GIOCA ANCORA"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The order of the views declared in XML is important here. The views first declared in `R.layout.activity_main` will be drawn before the views near the bottom of the XML file.

This means you may have to re-order the views in your layout file in order to get the design you are looking for.

P.s. if you post your layout file we can try to help further.